# Цикл bash, пока вызываемый php-скрипт возвращает значение нуль

Tags: php, bash

Сервер Ubuntu. Есть php-скрипт, который по завершении работы возвращает 1 либо 0:

```
<?php
...
if ($res) return 1;
else return 0;
?>
```

Необходимо написать  bash-сценарий, который запускает на выполнение php-скрипт, пока он возвращает значение 0.

Comment: `man bash` цикл `while`

Comment: пожалуйста, расшифруйте для новичка

Comment: Прочитать документацию по bash, в частности про цикл while.

Comment: В PHP return надо заменить на `echo`, либо `exit`. Сейчас значение возвращается вникуда

Answer (score 2):

Будет работать, при условии что в скрипте php стоит echo 1 или 0 и это единственный вывод скрипта

```
while [[ `php /myscript.php` -eq 0 ]]; do  #важно помнить:
#набор команд в случае если результат ноль
sleep 0.5     #полсекунды что бы случайно не перегрузить вебсервер =)
done #завершение цикла
```

upd: Действительно, данная конструкция будет работать, только если стоит вывод echo в php скрипте. 
Можно еще поставить код выхода, его тоже можно обработать средствами bash

php-скрипт:

```
...
if ($res) exit(1);
else exit(0);
?>
```

Тогда цикл в bash будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
while true; do
#либо
php /myscript.php || break
#либо
php /myscript.php
[[ $? -eq 1 ]] && break
#набор команд, если скрипт вернул 0
sleep 0.5
done
```

Comment: этот скрипт не будет работать

Comment: @TotalPusher можно уточнить почему?

Comment: потому что в том виде, до исправления, была синтаксическая ошибка